# Running PDFTron under non-interactive windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, pdftron

PDFTron is a 3rd party library used to convert files from one extension to a pdf document.

We're using it in our application successfully on multiple scenarios and operation systems.

Now, as we moved forward to automated build system such as TFS we are trying to run pdf conversion as part of the testing stage
We tried both ways, using standard UnitTest and we tried .Exe file which called by PowerShell script. None of the following ever succeeded running and throws the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: pdftron.Common.PDFNetException: Exception:
 ○ Message: An error occurred while converting the file.
 Detailed error:
 ○Document failed to open
 ○ Conditional expression: false
 ○ Filename   : Convert.cpp
 ○ Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPdf
 ○ Linenumber : 1825
 
 at pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(PDFDoc in_pdfdoc, String in_filename)
 at ImageComapareTool.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Running the executable\powershell script manually from the build server works just fine. which led us to think this is an issue when running under windows service

We ran into [this](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/faq_files/Converting_Documents_in_Windows_Service_or_ASP.NET_Application_using_PDFNet.pdf) document, but it failed to give us any good assumptions since we're running the service under local user.

Any lead regarding an optional solution\pointing in the right direction will be helpful

Comment: Under what account is the service running? Never mind - you said it local user - Does the local user have the required permissions.

Comment: User account, included in Administrator\PowerUser groups

Comment: The latest developer nightly builds contain much more logging. Please download the latest build and report the full error message here. Note, nightly developer builds are not for production usage, this would just be for testing.
http://www.pdftron.com/nightly/?p=experimental/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, after trying multiple directions such as experimental builds from Pdftron or psexec runs, we ran the TFS service in interactive mode which means an actual user has to be logged on to the TFS Build server.... So it's not the most convenient solution since it's very fragile but at least it works.

[image]